# authentication error for PostgreSQL user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

i am trying to run `rake db:create db:migrate db:seed` inside a ruby on rails project, i get an error saying `FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"`

Looking at other similar questions, a lot of people pointed out the validity bug in the pg_hba file, but as far as i can tell, there is no issue with it?

```
local   all             postgres                                md5    
local   all             all                                     peer
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

I also ran into this `sudo -u postgres psql -x -c "select * from pg_user where 
usename='p`and got the following:

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]---------
usename     | postgres
usesysid    | 10
usecreatedb | t
usesuper    | t
usecatupd   | t
userepl     | t
passwd      | ********
valuntil    | 
useconfig   |
```

more info : System Ubuntu 14.04 running in a vagrant box, with postgres v9.3.

**update:** I created a new database and a new user following the instructions found here[enter link description here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-add-postgresql-user-account/) , Added the new info to the database.yml file found in the config directory just to be sure I am using the DB user no the system user.

**update-2**: here is the info found in the database.yml file development:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: localhost
  database: db1
  pool: 5
  username: dev1
  password: dev1
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: localhost
  port: 5432
  database: db_test1
  pool: 5
  username: dev1
  password: dev1
```

Comment: Are you entering correct password or expecting to connect without it?

Comment: @alexius , I've set up the password in the database.yml file, and I tried logging in using su - postgres with that password, and it did work?

Comment: when you connecting under postgres user you most likely use peer authentication according to your pg_hba file (password is not needed). application probably connect to localhost instead of unix socket and receive password prompt. try to connect under postgres user and add `-h 127.0.0.1` to check if password is correct.

Comment: can you tell me the exact command format to use ? sorry as I am new to this

Comment: I meant to check with psql: `psql -h 127.0.0.1` to see if password correct

Comment: I just ran the command, the password didn't work

Comment: It's connecting as vagrant user , which doesn't have a password set; it uses ssh certificates to connect, during the setup I didn't set a password and the default one doesn't work as well which is also "vagrant" according the documentation.

Comment: `su - postgres` uses the *operating system* password for the *operating system* `postgres` user, which is totally unrelated to the database system `postgres` user. It sounds like you're using the wrong password and/or never actually set a password for the `postgres` database user.

Comment: how do i distinguish between the user postgres and the database user ? can you walk me through ?

Comment: @CraigRinger i created a new user and a database as shown in this link(http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-add-postgresql-user-account/) and added the new info to be used in the database.yml file for the ruby project to connect to, and I still get the same error, any ideas what else might be causing this ?

Comment: Also from what I know each postgresql data directory has its own set of users. So you should make sure that you have created the new user at the postgresql data directory you are trying to connect from rails.

Comment: @limekin tried running rails server, i got an error for the database while starting. but i didn't have the server running in the first place I was just preparing the dependencies of the project?

Comment: @limekin problem while using OauthProvider model:
 'FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "dev1"
problem while using ErrorGroups concenr:
 'FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "dev1"
problem while using attr_protected in Contribution model:
 'FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "dev1"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79517/discussion-between-limekin-and-nour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there could be quite a number of factors, it could be difficult to point out what is wrong in your setup. I guess I will just try to narrate how I use vagrant + rails + postgresql so I hope this helps you. This assumes that you have a fresh vagrant box with Ubuntu 14.04.

Let's say you have installed the necessary packages for ruby + rails. And now you are going to install postgresql.

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib libpq-dev
```

And then you would login to your postgresql admin user:

```
sudo su postgres
psql
```

Once logged in to the psql console, I would usually create a user named `vagrant`. I do this because postgresql defaults to using the current shell user as the database user when logging to the db console. This is more of a convenience(for me anyway). And then I would create the database in the console too. After that I give privileges for the database to the user `vagrant`.

```
CREATE USER vagrant WITH PASSWORD 'password';
CREATE DATABASE db1;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE db1 to vagrant;
```

After these steps, I would just add the appropriate `database.yml` config and run `rake db:migrate`. I find these workflow effective for me and I never encountered any permission problems with this. I also never touched `pg_hba.conf` with this setup. Please try this out and I hope this resolves your issues.

Cheers!